# Exception not getting captured when @Transactional (Rollback = Exception. Class)

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-rest

I'm facing an issue while using Exception handling(try/catch) along with @Transactional(Rollback = Exception. Class).

The customized exception message doesn't show up , only the rollback message will be shown :

exception message: ": "Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only",
"exception reason": "Failed due to Transaction Exception",

but if we remove @Transactional(Rollback = Exception. Class), the customized exception message is coming up , but this will not roll back.

Can anyone help us here, on getting the customized exception and transaction rolling back at the same time.

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive